# How to remove Chart Copyright?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

Look here :  https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/4qdan7k7/5/

How to remove the words `JS chart by amCharts`?

Comment: *"How to remove Chart Copyright?"* - Is your question "How do I pass off somebody else's work as my own?"

Comment: I need one vote to close this question. Please, give me close vote for close this question

Comment: @nnnnnn "How do I pass off somebody else's work as my own?". I think this is a really silly reasoning. The customer does not care one bit how or what library you used to draw the charts. Main reason for wanting to remove the copyright part is that it overlaps with other elements and also redirects to their page so it is not unusual to misclick and therefore open up a new tab with their website. Also, they do allow to remove the copyright element if you provide custom attribution somewhere, but none of the "official" methods work though.

Comment: @Karolis - If you wish to use a library that is subject to copyright/licensing conditions then you are legally obligated to respect those conditions regardless of what your customers think. If you don't like the conditions find another library. The answer below indicates that this particular library has an option to remove the branding - have you tried that?

Comment: @nnnnnn I am not arguing about the license, just said that your assumption about OPs intentions is misguided as I and quite a few people have landed to this and duplicate questions for other reasons. Currently, I just remove it though code temporarily while working so it doesn't get in the way so much. As for acquiring a license, that's not my decision to make anyway.

Answer (score 7):

you'll need to pay for it

- Removable amCharts branding

https://www.amcharts.com/online-store/